# backbone.js router

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, router

I would like to go to one of the links below the code:

```
    var  menukeuze;

   var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            "menukeuze": "getPost",
            "*actions": "defaultRoute" // matches http://example.com/#anything-here
        }
    });
    // Instantiate the router
    var app_router = new AppRouter;
    app_router.on('route:getPost', function (menukeuze) {
        // Note the variable in the route definition being passed in here
        if (menukeuze == 'Welkom') { MakeRequest_goto(menukeuze); }
        if (menukeuze == 'Dogs1') { MakeRequest_goto(menukeuze); }
        if (menukeuze == 'Dogs2') { MakeRequest_goto(menukeuze); }
    });
    app_router.on('route:defaultRoute', function (actions) {
        MakeRequest_goto('Welkom');
    });
    // Start Backbone history a necessary step for bookmarkable URL's
    Backbone.history.start();

function MakeRequest_goto (ganaarpagina) {
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#div-main-content').fadeOut(function() { $.ajaxSetup( {
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#div-main-content').fadeOut();
//                $('#content').hide();
//                $('#loading').show();
                    },
                    complete: function() {
//                $('#loading').hide();
//                $('#content').show();
                    },
                    success: function() {
//                $('#loading').hide();
                  $('#div-main-content').fadeIn();
//                  $('#div-main-content').show();
            }
        });
                    var $container = $("#div-main-content");
            //        $container.load(MakeRequest);
                    alert ("Loading: " + "page_" + ganaarpagina + ".php");
                            $container.load("page_" + ganaarpagina + ".php");
                }); }); }
```

I call these routes via:

```
<td>
 <a href="#/menu/Welkom" >
 <img src="images/test1.png" />
 </td>

<td>
 <a href="#/menu/Dogs1" >
 <img src="images/test2.png" />
</td>

<td>
 <a href="#/menu/Dogs2" >
 <img src="images/test3.png" />
</td>
```

When I type in the browser http://link.nl/#/menu/Welkom I get a perfect page, but the url looses the #. When I refresh the page, the webserver says: the requested URL is not found.
(this is because the URL changed from with "#" to without "#".)
When I click one of the href's it never works and I receive a :
GET http://link.nl/Welkom?_=1365638638131 404 (Not Found)

How can I load ajax via these routed URL's?
I've tried the setup and information of the following sites, but non did help:

http://thomasdavis.github.io/examples/restful-app/

http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/xkZtB/

[Backbone router listener not hitting hash tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101905/backbone-router-listener-not-hitting-hash-tag)

I've triend many more, but they end up the same, or don't have any "completed info".
I hope someone sees my problem?
The browser I'm using is: Chrome v26 on OSX.

The java scripts I'm using are:

```
<script src="http:////ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http:////ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
<script src='http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js'></script>
<script src='http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/backbone-min.js'></script>
```

The default route is working when I browse to the http://link.nl/ site.
Link.nl is not a real site, just as an example.
Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Try starting Backbone.history with pushState as true :

```
Backbone.history.start({pushState: "pushState" in window.history});
```

(The test only enable pushState for compatible browser. You can either set it to true or false manually. See the doc [here](http://backbonejs.org/#History))

This will force the url to always be without the hashbang (#!/). If you always want it, set it to false.

Now, for your 404 errors, it's because when you load a "real" url (link.nl/menu/Welkom), your web server (apache, nginx, etc) will search for this file (either a static one, or a virtual one via url rewriting). Since it can not find it (because you expect it to exists only in the frontend client, via Backbone), it will return a 404 errors before showing you the page.

To avoid the 404, you can set a url rewrite rules that will load the specific page containing your javascript, for any url you want.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out.
I've tried this pushState also, but unfortunately it's no solution for me.
I still get the following result in the console:

GET http://link.nl/menu/Welkom?_=1365671704329 404 (Not Found) jquery.min.js:5

Maybe I'm not having a problem with Backbone, but the jQuery implementation?
And still with enabling the pushState, The url changes from with # to without a #. 
And I think I still need the # to get everything working.

Comment: Okay, thank you your fast response and pointing me to the url rewrite stuff.
I'm going to find out how to solve it an post a solution here.

Comment: I've solved the url rewriting by reading: http://www.josscrowcroft.com/2012/code/htaccess-for-html5-history-pushstate-url-routing/

Now I receive the console message: "Uncaught Error: Backbone.history has already been started".     Going to dig in a little more.

Comment: Maybe you have `Backbone.history.start()` called twice on your code ?

Comment: Looking for it as I type :) Thx!

Comment: I think I need to rewrite the whole code for backbone.
I do have a normal html file with html code, div's etc. and also the backbone script code. I'm thinking I have to make use of the backbone view to show what needs to be displayed... I've got some reading to do.

Comment: Here's a good and complete article about Backbone, maybe it'll help! http://net.tutsplus.com/sessions/build-a-contacts-manager-using-backbone-js/ Good luck :)